# Why does f.label transform 'ALL' caps string to 'All' caps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an object that whose values are all caps, and I would like the `f.label` helper to print it out as all caps - without having to do a CSS transform.

Right now, if I have the string `AAPL` in my object, `f.label` spits it out as `Aapl`.

The reason I don't want to use a CSS transform is because the value of the object will not ALWAYS need to be all uppercase. I just want the `f.label` to output it exactly as it is stored in the db - preferably without any CSS shenanigans.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds like something is calling [`humanize()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize). This seems to happen, when Rails translates an element name to a label title. Probably you should define the text for the label explicit to it's form element.

```
<%= f.label(:aapl, 'AAPL') %>
```

or even

```
<%= f.label(:aapl, @yourVar) %>
```

Another option for you might be the translation ability, which Rails provides. This is valid for Rails > 3.1!

In your view:

```
<% form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In your en.yml:

```
en:
  helpers:
    label:
      post:
        title: 'Your Title'
```

Comment: The issue is that I need the label to be generated dynamically. For instance, given that the attribute is `topic.name`. How would that work? Clearly `f.label (topic.name, topic.name)` doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I am generating these labels inside a collection of checkboxes - so the label is inside an `each` with the local variable `topic` passed into the each block.

Comment: So you could create a helper method to create the label title from a specific field/checkbox. I don't want to be unfriendly, but this is not part of this question. You should ask a new question and provide some source code in it to clearify the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
f.label(topic).upcase.html_safe
```